# GoogleApp script optimization and improve css

Tags: css, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I hope this message finds you well. I am reaching out to seek your expertise and assistance with a challenge I'm currently facing in creating a commission calculator using GoogleScript. I have attached the project requirements, along with my GoogleSheet and the current GoogleScript code.

The issue revolves around optimizing achieving the desired output, and I am reaching out to the community for insights, guidance, and support. Your valuable expertise could make a significant difference.

If you could spare a moment to review the attached documents and provide any suggestions, modifications, or improvements to the existing code, it would be immensely appreciated.

I look forward to learning from the collective knowledge of this community.

Thank you in advance for your time and support. GoogleSheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pm_G90krKH3KsKV1tpSVaLei8I84XKHW86rbyJ6uh4E/edit?usp=sharing

Document - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XtUquNnHYQD4Aymuc4fIYStSQL7SXBWEF8KgPWcT7mM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: We are not a code writing service.  If you have specific questions about  the code feel free to ask them, otherwise plan to develop most of the code on your own.

Comment: @Cooper-I have written all the code. However, the UI and sometimes the output is not coming as expected.

Comment: Please post everything you need for the question in the question

Comment: @Cooper - I have mentioned it in doc because the code was so big.

Comment: Focus your question down to one issue and please post the code into the question

Comment: It sounds like your question is too broad for this forum

Comment: You can't use bounty to skip site rules. You can't have questions depending on external links.   Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files. Provide [mcve] in the question.

Comment: You spent 5 paragraphs just basically but nicely saying you are doing something and here is the attached code.  You might edit your question to actually describe your one challenge WITH that code.

Answer (score 2):

I was curious so I took a look at your project.

First I would split the file into three, one containing the html, one containing the css and one containing the js as [Shown Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#page.html).

Next you make three calls to the server to basically get the same data, `getData(poolId, empId)`, `getEditableTableData(poolId, empId)` and `getRightTableData(poolId, empId)`.  Simply pull all the data with one call and then in the client java script split it into the proper table.